# SQL group by get value on one column based on order of another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Suppose I have the following table in SQL:

| id | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | 10 |
| 1 | 2020 | 5 |
| 2 | 2019 | 10 |
| 2 | 2021 | 4 |
| 3 | 2018 | 2 |
| 3 | 2017 | 10 |

And for each id, I want the last value based on the year. The final table would be:

| id | year | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | 10 |
| 2 | 2021 | 4 |
| 3 | 2018 | 2 |

I know I have to use some sort of group by in id than order by year and get the first value, but I don't know what aggregate function that would be.

My attempt was to group by id while ordering by year and then getting the first value:

```
SELECT id, MAX(year), FIRST(value)
FROM t
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY year desc
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: I think you'll find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function:

```
 (partition by id order by year desc)
```

[The first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73773451/5459839) already gives the structure of the SQL making use of `row_number()` to filter the result. Here is an alternative:

```
select distinct id, 
       first_value(year)  over w as year,
       first_value(value) over w as value
from   t
window w as (partition by id order by year desc)
order by id;
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know how to use window functions

Answer (score 4):

Yet another option is using the [`FETCH FIRST n ROWS WITH TIES`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) clause, which allows to get the first rows with respect an ordering. Applying the ordering using the `ROW_NUMBER` window function, will make you extract all rows with ranking = 1, tied.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM tab 
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id_ ORDER BY year_ DESC)
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tpx64c4x6Y5AtXcKu6MwH/0).

Comment: That works too, but I think @trincot solution is more intuitive

Answer (score 2):

This is simple task for window functions:

```
with row_numbers as (
  select 
      *,
      row_number() over (partition by value order by year desc) rn
  from t
) select id, year, value from row_numbers where rn = 1;
```

[online sql editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql13/27e875139f4c4e7550bdb21ae762ae20/)

Comment: The "partition by value" is not needed in this case I think; maybe even incorrect?